# SEARCHING RECORDS FROM MYSQL WITH > OR < OPERATOR USING PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i am new in php, i want to search record from one date to another e.g. from 03 Jan 2010 to 16 Mar 2013. i have converted date into time() and stored as int 1428068707 in db as int value. How can i do this with sql query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use between operator in your query.

```
select * from Your_table 
where your_date between 'date1' and 'date2'
```

You can do it using comparison operators too:

```
SELECT * FROM Your_table 
WHERE your_date >= 'date1' AND your_date <= 'date2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date >= '2010-01-03 00:00:00' AND date <= '2013-03-16 00:00:00';
```

You can also use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-03' AND '2013-03-16';
```